# How to add object into array?

Tags: javascript

How would I add the object 'dining table' into living room items

```
let house = {
areas: {
    living Room: {
        items: ['tv' ,'sofa']
    },
    bedroom One: {
        items: ['bed' ,'washing machine'],
        windows: 3
    },
    bedroom Two:{
        items: ['bed' ,'bed' ,'desk'],
        windows: 4
    },
    kitchen:{
        items: ['fridge' ,'broken chair' ,'microwave']
    }
},
```

I don't know how to specifically add to the living room array

Comment: You are looking for `house['living Room'].items`.  So `house['living Room'].items.push('')`.

Comment: @gen_Eric:  Have you deliberately omitted `areas`?

Comment: push is what you need. It inserts an item in the end of the array. If you want it in the beginning if the array then use unshift

Comment: @PM77-1 I didn't see `areas` due to the formatting, my bad.  `house.areas['living Room'].items`

Comment: @PM77-1 and do you know how I would replace 'broken chair' with 'new chair'

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not having spaces in properties on JavaScript objects. You will be able to access them with dot notation without spaces. Then you can do the following:
`house.areas.livingRoom.items.push('item');`